# WampServer update from 2.5 to 3.1.3 version

Tags: php, mysql, apache, version, wampserver

I have to update my WampServer 2.5 to the latest 3.1.3 version.

These are the details of the different supported versions:
WAMPServer 2.5:
- Apache 2.4.9
- PHP 5.5.12
- MySQL 5.6.17

WAMPServer 3.1.3:
 - Apache 2.4.33
 - PHP 5.6.35
 - MySQL 5.7.21

I need to know which are the critical points of the 3 products that must be handled, more specifically:
- MySQL: is there any deprecated or not supported functions / data types / syntax that may result in data loss? For example, I'm aware that the date "0000-00-00" is no longer supported, and unfortunately we use it a lot in our database and our PHP code. Which is the best way to fix this issue?
- PHP: is there any generic syntax which is deprecated and need to be updated?
- Apache: I don't know too much about this web server; to copy the settings of our httpd.conf file into the new one would be enough?

In general, which is the best approach to avoid critical problems and make our System working with the new WampServer in a reasonable amount of time?

Any suggestion is appreciated,
Thank you very much!

Comment: The answers to all these question are available in the release/upgrade notes for MySQL and PHP.

Comment: Did you know you can install multiple versions of Apache/MySQL/PHP within WAMPServer. So you could simply BACKUP you current data. Install WAMPServer 3.2.3. Install ADDONS for Apache 2.4.10/ MySQL 5,6,17/ PHP5.5.12 and you would have Exactly the same environment running as before. Then you can ADDON upgrades to each piece and test for problems with each piece one by one

Comment: Checkout the [backup Repo](http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/?lang=en&allversions=afficher) for WAMPServer

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I didn't know about installing multiple versions within WAMPServer, I'll give it a try.

Comment: Please refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50600631/upgrade-wamp-safely