# Upgrade WAMP Safely

Tags: wamp, wampserver

How can I upgrade my WAMP Server **WITHOUT LOSING** my configuration? My current version is `WAMP 3.0.8` and I want to upgrade it to `WAMP 3.1.0`.

**FROM**

`WAMP 3.0.8`

- Apache 2.4.23
- MySQL 5.7.14
- PHP 5.6.25, 7.0.10

**TO**

`WAMP 3.1.0`

- Apache 2.4.27
- MySQL 5.7.19
- PHP 5.6.31, 7.0.23, 7.1.9

Comment: I mean... isn't the installer supposed to do that anyway ? Like just upgrading the core files and keeping your config.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

First as of WAMPServer 3 the WAMPServer code and the versions of Apache/PHP/MySQL/mariaDB are treated seperately.

So you can upgrade the WAMPServer version without touching anything of yours, like your website code or the versions of Apache/MySQL/PHP you are currently using.

So go to the [WAMPServer Backup Repo](http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/?lang=en) and download the `Wampserver update 3.1.3` (**or whatever the latest version of WAMPServer when you read this**) from the second section of the page titles `Wampserver Updates`.

That will upgrade the WAMPServer code, and nothing else. All code/databases will remain just as they were before.

#### Adding more/other versions of Apache/MySQL/PHP/mariaDB components

Again go to the repo, you will find a section on that page for each component. By default you only see the latest version of all the available addons, to see all available version of each component, click the `See all available versions` button.

Now you can download whichever version of Apache/PHP/MySQL that you want to ADDON to WAMPServer. Each ADDON component will install (remember to Run as Administrator when installing) the component but **not activate it**.

Remember WAMPServer can have multiple versions of each component available and you can switch between them to suit whichever project you are working on.

So after installing a new version of a component, you have the old one still active and the new one available to switch to.

See `left click wampmanager->Apache->version` for example and you will see all the available versions of Apache. This applies to PHP and MySQL and mariaDB as well.

So you can switch about between compatible version quite easily.

#### Switching versions of MySQL/mariaDB

This is the only component that requires a bit of extra work. Before switching from the old version of MySQL to the new one, backup the database(s) you want to move to the new version of MySQL.

Then switch the version of MySQL to the new one. Recreate all the user accounts so they match the old ones and then restore the backup you made earlier to the new Database.

NOTE: You have not removed the old version of the MySQL server, it is still there. It is now up to you whether you uninstall the old version or keep it around as a backup for a while.

Personally I have many versions of Apache/MySQL/PHP available to switch to. So for example if you have more than one project that you maintain, you can keep all the versions of any component available and when you have to go back to a project, its all there waiting for you.

It is also great if you are considering upgrading an old project to a new version of PHP for example. You can switch between versions at the click of a menu while looking for incompatibilities.

Comment: Who is *aviatechno.net* and what is their relationship to **wampserver.com**?

Comment: @gt That site is run by the guy that maintains and build releases for WAMPServer. He uses it because he can get release out quicker than SourceForge, because SourceForge did a few things people didn't like and so stopped using it. And because it is 10 times easier to navigate than SourceForge. If you prefer all code is also on SourceForge but you may have trouble finding it

Comment: Warning: My anti virus program detected a virus !!

Comment: @Black I doubt it. But because you are downloading stuff that has comms in it from a place it does not know, it is being super careful. Most decent Virus checkers now have a feature that sends the code home and analyses it. Do that and it will get a clean bill of health in a couple of minutes. If your virus checker does not do that, get a new one

Comment: @RiggsFolly, it is windows defender though.

Comment: once the great answers i ever read on stack over flow